# Shifting from console application to windows application

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have used Visual Studio to create console applications. Now I am shifting to a windows form application and I don't understand where should my code go, how to access the text boxes (seen tutorials, do stuff in form.h itself, nothing in main.cpp).

The 600 line code I have written for the console app involving many functions and variables should do the same job .. only the interfacing has to be changed, i.e receiving input from text boxes than a file.

I have made attempts only to see errors in sourceannotation.h Is there any source from where I can understand all this?

ADD ON: I have understood how to open,create and run simple applications like calculator and stuff. I want to know how to do more robust programming where one button starts a process involving 15-20 functions and operating over several variables. I have placed the #includes, #defines and namespace std with one's already given, placed my global variables after windows form designer generated code and my main in the button click event.

If you can please do the minimal of telling me the syntax of function definition in form.h and point out why can all the above attempt could give rise to over 150 errors in sourceannotations.h ps: not a user defined file.

Answer (score 0):

Create new MFC project, either modal dialog or single document interface (you have to decide which one, based on the way your console application works). Build and run it to see your first empty application. Experiment in this project a bit. If it's modal dialog then add some buttons and handlers for them. If it's SDI then add some menu items and handlers for them.

When done learning and experimenting move your source files to new project, and bind it with event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a C++ Windows Forms Application which would have a similar dev. environment to lets say c# so if you are familiar with WinForms dev. in C# you should be able to use this configuration. Also, you could create a Win32 Application, in which case you would have to do all the interface creation using SDI or MDI methods configured by you. This is a much harder process since you may have to define the application message pump without much boiler plate code.

Comment: Ok, if you create a C++ Windows Forms Application using the template in create new project window, you will be given a skeleton project which you can then copy your code to. Then drag and drop controls unto the default window; for example a button and then add the code for the click event of that button.

Comment: yes i did that.. the main() of the original console app went into the click event and the rest of the variables and functions in the global scope .. as they were before. When i try to build it .. it gives over 150 errors in sourceannotations.h

Comment: sourceannotations.h does not exist in my template. Is it a user defined header file?